# Adding Pagination to Instagram Search API [AJAX + PHP]

Tags: php, ajax, pagination, instagram, instagram-api

first post on stackoverflow!
Using a modified version of this script http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/instagram-photo-search/

I've changed it to a user search instead of a tag search.. adding the two api calls one for ID and then the other for Images by Username..

I've seen other examples of Pagination being used.. **but not sure how to apply it to my current code**.. Fairly new with the instagram API

Feel free to use my code! It's very nice ajax way of retrieving photos per user. **I took out the CURL portion for readablility.**

I would simply like to call something like 20 photos per page. **THankS.**

**instasearch.php**

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
define("YOUR_TOKEN", 'TOKEN HERE');
$query = $_POST['q'];
$userid = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?count=1&q=' . $query . '&access_token='. YOUR_TOKEN;
$clnum = mt_rand(1,3);

// function get_curl($url) WOULD GO HERE //

// SEARCH FOR ID //
$response = get_curl($userid);

if ($response){
    foreach(json_decode($response)->data as $item){     
        $id = $item->id;

        $user[] = array(
        "id" => htmlspecialchars($id),

        );
   }
}

// SEARCH BY ID //
$api ='https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/' . $id . '/media/recent/?' . '&access_token='. YOUR_TOKEN . '&count=33';

$response2 = get_curl($api);
$images = array();

if($response2){
    foreach(json_decode($response2)->data as $item){        
        $src = $item->images->standard_resolution->url;
        $thumb = $item->images->thumbnail->url;
        $url = $item->link;
        $count = $item->likes->count;

        $images[] = array(
        "src" => htmlspecialchars($src),
        "thumb" => htmlspecialchars($thumb),
        "url" => htmlspecialchars($url),
        "count" => htmlspecialchars($count)
        );
    }
}

print_r(str_replace('\\/', '/', json_encode($images)));

//if($likes)
//print_r(json_encode($likes));
//
die();
?>
```

**ajax.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var sfield = $("#s");
    var container = $("#photos");
    var timer;

    function instaSearch() {
        $(sfield).addClass("loading");
        $(container).empty();
        var q = $(sfield).val();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://192.168.0.3/igpanel/image-select/instasearch.php',
            data: "q="+q,
            success: function(data){
                $(sfield).removeClass("loading");

                $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                    var ncode = '<span class="p"><span id="likes"><i style="color:#E74C3C" class="fa fa-heart"></i> '+data[i].count+' likes</span><!--<a href="'+data[i].url+'" target="_blank">--><img id="'+data[i].url+'" src="'+data[i].thumb+'"></a></span>';
                    $(container).append(ncode);
                });
            },
            error: function(xhr, type, exception) { 
                $(sfield).removeClass("loading");
                $(container).html("Error: " + type); 
            }
        });
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<section id="sform">
    <input type="text" id="s" name="s" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Username..." autocomplete="off">
    </section>
    <div id="image_container">
    <section id="photos"></section>
    </div>
```